# Fortran undefined reference when library is loaded and contains the sought after symbol

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, mpich, cgns

I have modules compiled on their own and then linked in an executible to form a program. I am calling symbols from the cgns library, but some of them throw an undefined reference error, even though the symbol exists in the library.

This code seems to compile fine in older gcc ~4 to 8 versions, but not my current version 13. I am also using the mpif90 compiler from mpich.

So I recreated the problem with a dummy code. Here is my setup with a dummy code that recreates the issue exactly:

- Fedora 39
- GCC 13 via `dnf install gcc gfortran`
- MPICH 4.1 via `dnf install mpich-devel`
- CGNS 4.4 via `dnf install cgnslib-mpich-devel`
- HDF5 1.12.1 via `dnf install hdf5-mpich-devel` (not sure if relevant here)

The reference in question is `cg_nbases_f`, so doing

```
me@pc:dir$ objdump -T $MPI_LIB/libcgns.so | grep cg_nbases_t
00000000000a44b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000055  Base        cg_nbases_f
```

The dummy code consists of two files, a module `cgnsreading.f90` and a program `cgnsread.f90`

`cgnsreading.f90`:

```
module cgnsreading
    implicit none

    private

    public talk_to_cgns

contains

    subroutine error_check()
        print *, 'hi I am the bane of arthropods'
    end subroutine error_check

    subroutine talk_To_cgns()
        character(100) :: errmsg
        integer :: i = 1
        integer :: nbases = 1
        integer :: ierr

        call cg_get_error_f(errmsg)
        print *, errmsg ! Should print that there is no error
        call error_check() ! Should print its guts

        call cg_nbases_f(i,nbases,ierr) ! Throws undefined reference error

    end subroutine talk_To_cgns

end module cgnsreading
```

`cgnsread.f90`:

```
program cgnsread
    use cgnsreading
    implicit none

    call talk_to_cgns()
    
end program cgnsread
```

Compiling it and linking in the following way produces the error:

```
me@pc:dir$ mpif90 cgnsreading.f90 -c
me@pc:dir$ mpif90 cgnsread.f90 -c
me@pc:dir$ mpif90 cgnsreading.o cgnsread.o -lcgns -o cgnsread
/usr/bin/ld: cgnsreading.o: in function `__cgnsreading_MOD_talk_to_cgns':
cgnsreading.f90:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `cg_nbases_f_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My thought was that there were either some issues related to the module having private subroutines, but that is ruled out because the error occures by calling the public subroutine.

I was also suspecting that it's due to the compiler ignoring the linking flag (flags order), but when that happens, `cg_get_error_f` throws the same error. Hence, why I tested that as well.

I expected that the references would only be available in the devel versions of the cgns library, but that doesn't seem to be the case because I am using the devel version.

There was a suspicion that a different library was installed somewhere else, and indeed there is, but it also contains the missing reference.

I do not know if this is a specific problem to cgns or its installation, but I haven't tested this with something else.

Why would a library provide a symbol but not the other, even though both exist in the same library.

The same error occures on another pc with the same setup as mentioned above. So the problem can be replicated.

Comment: Please follow the instructions displayed when adding tags. Tag [tag:fortran90] or any other version tag should not be used on its own. Use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: Symbol `cg_nbases_f_` is missing but the library only contains `cg_nbases_f`. These are not the same. Does the library provide any Fortran interfaces or modules? If yet, you must use them. If not, you need to create them. You cannot just call the subroutine as an.external Fortran one without tricks like `-fno-underscoring` (not recommmended).

Comment: Thanks, I think you put me on the right track here. And using `-fno-underscoring` is actually problimatic in my case, because the library provides the other symbol `cg_get_error_f_`, but not without the underscore `cg_get_error_f`. I need both, so I will check for interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the symbol names defined in the library:

```
nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgns.so | grep nbases
```

```
0000000000047070 T cg_nbases
0000000000084900 T cg_nbases_f
```

The symbol that we are looking for is there, but the `mpif90` compiler has appended an underscore to the name. In principle this is to prevent clashes between Fortran and C names.

Update `cgnsreading.f90` and add `use cgns`:

```
module cgnsreading
    use cgns
    implicit none

    private

    public talk_to_cgns

contains

    subroutine error_check()
        print *, 'hi I am the bane of arthropods'
    end subroutine error_check

    subroutine talk_to_cgns()
        character(100) :: errmsg
        integer :: i = 1
        integer :: nbases = 1
        integer :: ierr

        call cg_get_error_f(errmsg)
        print *, errmsg ! Should print that there is no error
        call error_check() ! Should print its guts

        call cg_nbases_f(i,nbases,ierr) ! Throws undefined reference error

    end subroutine talk_to_cgns

end module cgnsreading
```

When you compile that you'll need to specify the include path for `cgns.mod`, which should be located at `/usr/include/cgns.mod`.

```
mpif90 cgnsreading.f90 -c -I/usr/include/
mpif90 cgnsread.f90 -c
mpif90 cgnsreading.o cgnsread.o -lcgns -o cgnsread
```

[image]

I don't have a Fedora 39 system but I can replicate with Docker. Follow these steps to get it set up.

```
FROM fedora:39

RUN dnf install -y wget gcc-gfortran hdf5-devel cgnslib openmpi openmpi-devel

RUN wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/39/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/cgnslib-devel-4.4.0-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm && \
    rpm -i cgnslib-devel-4.4.0-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm && \
    rm -f cgnslib-devel-4.4.0-2.fc39.x86_64.rpm

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/

COPY *.f90 .

RUN mpif90 cgnsreading.f90 -c -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/
RUN mpif90 cgnsread.f90 -c
RUN mpif90 cgnsreading.o cgnsread.o -lcgns -o cgnsread
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, while I think your answer does solve the problem, interestingly enough, my cgns build does not include the `cgns.mod` you mention. So I will probably have to install it from source to get the module. I will check that out, and get back to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Okay, let me see if I can replicate your environment. What operating system are you on (name and version)? And how did you install CGNS? I'm assuming that you used a package manager. What version of the package?

Comment: You mentioned Fedora 39. Is that what you are working on?

Comment: Yup! This is Fedora 39 and the prerequisites are mentioned in the top of the question. I installed cgns from source, and that created `cgns.mod`. This fixed my problem so I will accept your answer. But now I wonder, why installing cgns from dnf does not include `cgns.mod`, even though it includes all the fortran interfaces in the library. Thanks again!

Comment: I added a `Dockerfile` at the end of my answer with the required steps to get this working on Fedora 39.

Comment: Thanks, actually, that makes sense now, I found the missing module, the default path for the `cgns.mod` was in `/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules`, with my `cgnslib-mpich-devel` it went to `/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/mpich`. So I added `-I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/mpich` and that worked!